# How to execute a python script with a custom command?

Tags: python, command

Hello i want to run a specific script by for example typing "run" will run the script.
i found some people talking about envoirment vars but i dont know what to do can anyone help me?

Comment: Please be more clear. Do you want to run a **python** script or run just any old script? Do you want to run the script from the command-line or from a python program?

Comment: Do you mean, that in order to run the script you'll have to give it an argument, like:
`main.py -command run`?

Comment: What operating system? This tends to be OS-specific.

Comment: i want to run a python script with a custom command in cmd or any command line  i want the command be like this ">run main.py". also sorry im new to stack overflow i dont know how to use this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do `alias python="run"`